# Laravel Eloquent related tables syntax

Tags: laravel, object, eloquent

I have three tables, staff, locations, and departments. The staff table has fields for location and department which are numeric. The locations and department tables have id fields which are being used by the staff table to reference the location and department details.

I am trying to display the staff details in a view but can't seem to find the correct syntax within the Laravel documentation to do this without creating an associative array.

This is what I have in my staffController file

```
public function index()
{
    $staff_details =  Staff::all();


    foreach($allStaff as $staff_member){
        $location = Locations::find($staff_member->location);
        $department= Departments::find($staff_member->department);

        $staff_details[] = array(
            'id' => $staff_member->id,
            'first_name' =>$staff_member->first_name,
            'surname' =>$staff_member->surname,
            'job_title' => $staff_member->job_title,
            'location'  => $location->location,
            'department'  => $department->department,

        );
    }


    return view('staff.index', compact('staff_details'));

}
```

but this is passing an array. I want to pass a staff_details object doing something like
`$staff_details = Staff::all()->locations($staff->location)->departments($staff->department);`

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you [set up the proper relationships in your model](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships), use the [`with`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$staff_details = Staff::with('locations', 'departments')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I have my relationships set up in the locations and departments  models as  public function staff()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Staff');
    } and in the staff model as   public function locations()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Locations', 'location');
    }

    public function departments()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Departments', 'department');
    }  but it is returning null for the location and department, any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I realised that I needed the foreign key and the local key in the relationships in the models and also needed to reference them properly in the blade so the relations ships where return $this->hasOne('App\Locations', 'id', 'location'); and referenced in the blade as {{ $staff->locations->location }} thanks for the input, great help